# Migrating data from SQLEXPRESS local DB to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012

I have a process that is importing data from CSV files to a local SQL Express DB, then I can use the SQL Server 2012 migration tool to migrate the database to SQL Azure (as described in http://bit.ly/WRPSZs).  It works great for moving a database.

However, it's a bit of a pain when the data changes and I just want to freshen the DB.  I tried changing my scripts that do this to just connect to the SQL Azure DB, but ran into the problem that SQL Azure apparently doesn't support BCP:

```
Msg 40526, Level 16, State 1, Server Xxxxxx, Line 37
'BULK' rowset provider not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

So I'm back to importing to SQL Express, then dropping the DB, exporting it from SQL Express and then going and recreating the DB users and roles.

Anyone have a better way?

Comment: have you been able to do any further tests on your issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Azure documentation you should be able to import data using the BCP command. 
see: [BCP and SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/21/10014019.aspx)

To confirm that it was working I also went and tested it out. For my test I inserted 10 rows of data from my csv file called **import.txt**.  I used the **-t,** syntax to specify that it was comma delimited.

Here's the (redacted) syntax of the command that I used:

```
bcp database_name.schema.table in C:\import.txt -c -U username@servername -S servername.database.windows.net -P password -t,
```

From here I could see the following results

```
Starting copy...

10 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 390    Average : (25.64 rows per sec.)
```

I have seen a few instances where inserting a very large amount of data can cause the import to fail but that would probably be a different error than what you're seeing.